# Need constraints for y position or height when height is unambiguous with stack views in stack views

Tags: swift, xml, interface-builder

I created a "TitleDetails" view below and I'd like to stack that titleDetails view into another reusable view.  There are no errors thrown for the TitleDetails constraints.  I'd just like to stack 2 TitleDetails views into a new view.

[image]

However, when I do the constraints it appears I need the Y position for height, however the height of titleDetails should be determined by its contents and the space between the two is constrained as well. So I'm not seeing where the ambiguity is coming from.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="18122" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="18093"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="TitleDetails" customModule="WholeVC" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="detailsLabel" destination="pjO-IR-TuP" id="EkZ-wc-LOm"/>
                <outlet property="stackBottom" destination="W1y-Me-M1S" id="ykw-d7-bz9"/>
                <outlet property="stackLeading" destination="6n3-Qg-845" id="ghK-h8-OBL"/>
                <outlet property="stackTop" destination="Ey8-Pq-GRr" id="WOw-Q0-zc2"/>
                <outlet property="stackTrailing" destination="m9b-I7-Nwj" id="ly8-lY-3zf"/>
                <outlet property="stackView" destination="pIM-2q-cOU" id="LvK-Yk-LHf"/>
                <outlet property="titleLabel" destination="G5U-AG-1Se" id="4KM-9f-LQA"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="208" height="72"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" spacing="5" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pIM-2q-cOU">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="208" height="72"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="1000" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Title" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="wordWrap" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="G5U-AG-1Se">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="36.5" height="72"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Details Details Details" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="wordWrap" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pjO-IR-TuP">
                            <rect key="frame" x="41.5" y="0.0" width="166.5" height="72"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                    </subviews>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="pjO-IR-TuP" firstAttribute="width" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="G5U-AG-1Se" secondAttribute="width" id="EGR-ZT-2ID"/>
                    </constraints>
                </stackView>
            </subviews>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vUN-kp-3ea"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="pIM-2q-cOU" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" id="6n3-Qg-845"/>
                <constraint firstItem="pIM-2q-cOU" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" id="Ey8-Pq-GRr"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="pIM-2q-cOU" secondAttribute="bottom" id="W1y-Me-M1S"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="pIM-2q-cOU" secondAttribute="trailing" id="m9b-I7-Nwj"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="94.20289855072464" y="-113.16964285714285"/>
        </view>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Xof-7G-Flv">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="355" height="279"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="awM-nF-Vev" customClass="TitleDetails" customModule="WholeVC" customModuleProvider="target">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="355" height="103"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                </view>
                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mcx-Fg-GMg" customClass="TitleDetails" customModule="WholeVC" customModuleProvider="target">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="172" width="355" height="107"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                </view>
            </subviews>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="art-6S-teo"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="awM-nF-Vev" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Xof-7G-Flv" secondAttribute="leading" id="3Sp-vC-vfu"/>
                <constraint firstItem="awM-nF-Vev" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Xof-7G-Flv" secondAttribute="trailing" id="L4H-5I-T0j"/>
                <constraint firstItem="awM-nF-Vev" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Xof-7G-Flv" secondAttribute="top" id="Xcm-9t-hJx"/>
                <constraint firstItem="mcx-Fg-GMg" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="awM-nF-Vev" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="69" id="Yh4-pM-WP6"/>
                <constraint firstItem="mcx-Fg-GMg" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Xof-7G-Flv" secondAttribute="trailing" id="dUB-H0-Zm1"/>
                <constraint firstItem="mcx-Fg-GMg" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Xof-7G-Flv" secondAttribute="bottom" id="feT-Rh-Vs7"/>
                <constraint firstItem="mcx-Fg-GMg" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Xof-7G-Flv" secondAttribute="leading" id="pD5-5k-VJf"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="94.927536231884062" y="67.96875"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: "the height of titleDetails should be determined by its contents" no, it's ambiguous

Comment: Because the title and detail label's intrinsic sizes aren't pushing at the stack view. Instead, the stack view is pulling on the title and detail label's sizes.

Comment: Intrinsic size in xib is a hard to work with. Maybe you just want an equal height constraint? Right-click and drag from the top titleDetail to the bottom titleDetail view, then release and click "Equal Heights"

Comment: No, I want the heights of each to be determined by the heights of the contents the label's heights.

Comment: Wait...Oh, I see, the width isn't constrained...Hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've shown would be very easy to implement via code, rather than XIB files.

However, the reason you're getting the ambiguity is because interface builder cannot determine the intrinsic height as you have designed it.

***IF*** your current implementation gives you the desired layout at run-time, you can get rid of the "ambiguous" errors / warnings by giving your top `TitleDetails` view a "Placeholder" intrinsic height.

Select the view, and then in the Size Inspector pane:

[image]

Comment: Ah! or a placeholder intrinsic width! Thank you this is what I've been looking for.